# How to load data into mysql table but ignore the blank lines

Tags: mysql

I am using the following statement in order to insert data from file.

```
load data infile 'filename.csv'
ignore 
into table tbl (clo);
```

I need to ignore the blank lines in the file. How can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot skip lines unless they are at the beginning of the file which you can use the `IGNORE N LINES` option.

Use sed before importing:

`sed -i '/^\s*$/d' filename.csv`

For more details:
[Delete empty lines using SED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414410/delete-empty-lines-using-sed)

Comment: Ah, much more helpful. Always remember: __Links Die__.

Comment: If I have to import a 10 gig file, I really don't want to be pre-processing it, but I guess I can just write a custom program every time I want to import data efficiently...

Answer (score -1):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename.csv'
INTO TABLE your_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

The \r is necessary on Windows files, if you're running this on *nix you shouldn't need them.

Comment: Does not work. Gives me an error in the syntax. I need to specify the column exactly as I posted in my statement (I need the lines to be inserted in a specific column).

Comment: @JuryA Yes, this does not answer the question